# Is this relation symmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

$R = \{(X, Y) \in \mathscr{P}(A)^2| X \subset Y \text{ and }X \neq Y \}$

I know that $(X,Y) \in R$ holds true since $X \subset Y$.

However I'm unsure if $(Y,X) \in R$ since if $Y \subset X$ then that would make $X = Y$ (I think) breaking the condition that $X \neq Y$. Am I correct in thinking this and concluding that this relation is not symmetric?

Comment: Thanks for the format fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you are correct. The relation is not symmetric, and for the reason you post.

$$(X\subseteq Y\; \text{ AND }\;Y\subseteq X) \iff X=Y$$

Hence, since  $(X, Y)\in R \implies (X\subseteq Y$ and $X\neq Y$),  it cannot be the case that $Y \subseteq X$.

Comment: Am I safe to assume that it's not anti-symmetric either since even if ((X,Y)∈R and (Y,X)∈R) X != Y so it cannot be anti-symmetric either?

Comment: Antisymmetry holds *[vacuously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).* Antisymmetry holds **unless** ALL the following hold for some $X, Y$: there is an  $(X, Y) \in R$ and $(Y, X) \in R$ and $X \neq Y$. So it will never fail to be antisymmetric.

Comment: Hmm damn ok I thought that X = Y for it to be anti-symmetric.

Comment: You're right that a relation is antisymmetric if the following implication is true: $$[(X, Y)\in R \text{ AND } (Y, X) \in R] \implies X=Y$$ Recall that an implication is false only when the antecedent is true, but the conclusion is false. Since the antecedent is never true in this relation (it can never happen that both $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$, the implication is vacuously true. Hence, since the implication is always true for this relation, it is antisymmetric.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks!